# Multple Cubes with different materials in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm teaching myself three.js and am playing around with different materials on cubes.  I'm trying to add 3 cubes to a scene, each with a different material, to compare differences side by side.

The issue is that only `cube1` currently renders.  The other cubes do not appear in the browser.  Any help in fixing the issue would be greatly appreciated.

```
<body>
    <script src="../three.js-master/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../three.js-master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script>
        var camera, scene, renderer;
        var controls
        var cube1, cube2, cube3;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {
            //Renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias: true} );
            var width = window.innerWidth;
            var height = window.innerHeight;
            renderer.setSize( width, height );
            document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            //Create Cubes
            //Normal
            var cube1Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2,1,1 );
            var cube1Material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
            cube1 = new THREE.Mesh( cube1Geometry, cube1Material );
            cube1.position.set( 0,0,0 );
            scene.add( cube1 );

            //Lambert
            var cube2Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1,2,1 );
            var cube2Material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {color: 0xff0000, transparent: true, opacity: 05} );
            cube2 = new THREE.Mesh( cube2Geometry, cube2Material );
            cube2.position.set( -10,0,0 );
            scene.add( cube2 );

            //Phong
            var cube3Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1,1,2 );
            var cube3Material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {shininess: 1} );
            cube3 = new THREE.Mesh( cube3Geometry, cube3Material );
            cube3.position.set( 10,0,0 );
            scene.add( cube3 );

            //Create Camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (45, width/height, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.y = 30;
            camera.position.z = 30;
            camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3( 0,0,0 ) );

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        }

        function animate() {
            controls.update();
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continued digging into the issue brought to light (pun intended) that lambert and phong materials require a light source.  They were both being rendered, but were not visible due to lack of light.

Added:

```
//Light Source
var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xff0000, 1, 100 );
light.position.set( 20,20, 20 );
scene.add( light );
```

And they now appear in the browser.